# Can't get path of image in NSBundle?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, nsbundle

I am trying to get the path of an image while UITesting. I've tried multiple ways as shown under here, but none are working?

Name of image file is: TestImage.fff

```
NSBundle* testBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]];
NSString* testImage = [testBundle pathForResource:@"TestImage.fff" ofType:@"fff"];
NSString* testImage2 = [testBundle pathForImageResource:@"TestImage"];
NSURL* testImage3 = [testBundle URLForResource:@"TestImage" withExtension:@"fff"];
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you check that your `TestImage.fff` file is copied inside a `Copy Bundle Resources`  of the test target ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside XCode, select your test target inside the target list. Then select the `Build Phases` tab and inside the `Copy Bundle Resources` phase, add the required resources.

[image: Example of project]